# How to find the limit of (an) when (an)n=1?

Tags: real-analysis

Im working through a proof and have found that the limit of a sequence $(a_n)n=1$. How do I solve L for the limit of $(a_n)=L$?

Answer (score 2):

$$a_n\times n=1$$

$$a_n=\frac1n$$

$$L=\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac1n=0$$

Comment: Thank you, I wasn't sure if I was able to set them equal like that.

Comment: @MeatheadMathematician No problem.  cheers!